# Ramda - How to sort array with nested object with string to number conversion

Tags: ramda.js

I am trying to sort the array which looks like this:

```
const testArray = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "nodeLayout": {
      "x": "12.0",
      "y": "1.0",
      "width": 200,
      "height": 87
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "nodeLayout": {
      "x": "1.0",
      "y": "1.0",
      "width": 200,
      "height": 87
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "nodeLayout": {
      "x": "0.0",
      "y": "1.0",
      "width": 200,
      "height": 87
    }
  }
]
```

I was trying to sort it with this:

```
R.pipe(
  R.pluck('nodeLayout'),
  R.map(R.pipe(R.props(['x']), R.join(','))),
  R.sortWith([R.ascend(parseFloat)])
)(testArray)
```

Which is working fine but I am getting only `x` values sorted and I am not able to fit this sort into this one:

```
R.pipe(
  R.filter(
    R.allPass([
      R.pathEq(['nodeLayout', 'y'], '1.0'),
      R.propEq('group', 4)
    ]
  ))
  // I tried to add it here: R.sortBy(R.path(['nodeLayout', 'x'])) but I need to parse string first and I have no idea how to combine those
)(testArray)
```

To sum up, I am trying to get the whole object with all properties sorted.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you combine your two approaches, you should be able to achieve what you're wanting.

The main thing being that you can `R.pipe` the call to `parseFloat` after obtaining the value you'd like to sort with `R.path`. This piped function can be provided as the argument to `R.sortBy`.

```
R.pipe(
  R.filter(
    R.allPass([
      R.pathEq(['nodeLayout', 'y'], '1.0'),
      R.propEq('group', 4)
    ]
  )),
  R.sortBy(R.pipe(R.path(['nodeLayout', 'x']), parseFloat))
)(testArray)
```

Comment: I knew that I was close... Thank you :)